# Connecting to Volttron Central server from Windows PC on device LAN

Tags: volttron

I have a RPi running an instance of volttron-central.  I can VNC into the RPi and view the Web UI from a browser pointed to localhost, so I know that it is running.  However, when I attempt to connect from a PC connected to the same LAN using the RPi's IP address, I get "refused to connect" error.

Is this a security feature?  If so, is there any-way of viewing the WEB UI from a different machine, or does it need to be running an instance of volttron-central locally?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit your config file to use an external address (e.g. not 127.0.0.1).  In VOLTTRON_HOME (~/.volttron) edit the config file.  Change the bind-web-address setting to equal (what you have above as 192.168.1.4) to http://192.168.1.4:8080.  Then restart the platform.

Note: you should also make sure your /etc/hosts file has a mapping from the 192.168.1.4 onto your hostname, then you could goto https://foo:8080 rather than using the address.  This will work with the bind-web-address, but not the vip-address.